# Android, assigning value to variables in onActivityResult method?

Tags: android, variables, variable-assignment, subactivity

I'm trying to retrieve some information from my onActivityResult method, in my case is a picture the user has selected in a subactivity, i believe that is working fine, what i am having problems with is when i try to assign that picture (in form of a byte array) to a variable i have in my main activity. I'm trying to use that variable in a onClick method, but for some reason when i try to use that variable it's value is always null.
what could be happening?
here is the code:

```
poptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
            final Intent i;
            switch(pos){
            // Adjunta imagen
            case 0:
                i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivityForResult(i,1);
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "MIERDA!!", 30).show();
                break; // more cases below, not relevant to my question....
                }
        }

    });
```

my onActivityResult method:

**EDIT: The solution was to change**

```
if(resultCode==1)
```

**to:**

```
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
```

**turns out, RESULT_OK actually equals -1.**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent pic){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, pic);
    if(resultCode==1){

        Uri selectedpic = pic.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmappic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver(), 
                    selectedpic);

            ByteArrayOutputStream picstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmappic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, picstream);
            setPicture(picstream.toByteArray());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

my onClickListener method where i'm trying to use the picture that was set by my setPicture method above.

```
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle usrpostData = new Bundle();
                if(txtMsg.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "MSG", 10).show();
                }else{
                    String msg = txtMsg.getText().toString();
                    usrpostData.putString("message", msg);
                    if(getPicture()==null){
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"NULL",30).show();
                    }else{
                        try {
                            // do something with the picture...

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

As you can see i put a little test, and the getPicture method always return null, i tried .equals instead of == and it makes my app crash.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post under which Activity method you call btnSend.onClickListener()?  If it is in onCreate(), then the original Activity instance where you saved the pic is already destroyed.

Comment: @hopia yes my btnSend.onClickListener() is on my onCreate() method, in the main activity where i call the subactivity.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, are u sure u r checking the right parameter in onActivityResult()? I think it should be requestCode. resultCode usually returns RESULT_OK, RESULT_CANCEL, etc.  think u need to check for requestCode. Nothing related to ure query though :(

Comment: Also can u put the code for everything related to setPicture and getPicture?

Comment: @hopia thanks, i found out the problem, i was checking resultCode to be 1, when RESULT_OK actually equals -1, i changed the code and now the picture is no longer null, thank you for your help, by the way, how can i mark this as solved? there are no real answers, just your comments..

Comment: Nice to hear that.  Well, you can post your solution as an answer for others to see... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change

```
if(resultCode==1)
```

to:

```
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
```

turns out, RESULT_OK actually equals -1.